# Vagrantの仮想環境にホストマシン以外からアクセスすると Connetion timed out してしまう

Tags: network, vagrant

Vagrantで構築した仮想マシンに対して、ホストマシンのPC以外からアクセスしたいです。
   三つある仮想マシンのうち一つはアクセスできていますが、それ以外の二つがなぜかできません。

現状は、

- いずれのマシンもVgarnat fileでconfig.vm.network "public_network", ip: '192.168.1.100'
  しています。（ipは第３オクテット以降を変えています）
- bridge : 'en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)'などを省略するとup時に聞かれるとありますが、聞かれません。
- 接続できるマシンを接続したままにしていようがしていまいが、２つの仮想マシンがConnetion timed　outです。（２つの接続できないマシンだけが常に接続できない）
- ホストマシンからはすべて正常にアクセスできます。（==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => Now on port 2200　　vagrant boxで設定されているのか、自分では設定していませんが、sshのポート衝突は回避されています）
- config.vm.boot_timeout=2000してます。

以下は接続できないマシンのvagrant fileで有効になっているものの抜粋です。

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
　　　　config.vm.box = "geerlingguy/centos7"
　　　　config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9000, host: 9000
　　　　config.vm.network "public_network", ip: '192.168.39.14'
　　　　config.vm.synced_folder "./shared", "/home/vagrant/guest_folder"
　　　　config.vm.boot_timeout=2000

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  　　config.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.3"
      config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 4200, host: 4200
      config.vm.network "public_network", ip: '192.168.33.11'
      config.vm.synced_folder "./host_folder", "/home/vagrant/guest_folder", type: 'virtualbox', create: true
      config.vm.boot_timeout=2000
```

ご教示いただければ幸いです。

追記： ifconfigの結果
接続できないマシン１

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe8d:7713  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:8d:77:13  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1381  bytes 156697 (153.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1084  bytes 167110 (163.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.39.14  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.39.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fedb:3e14  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:db:3e:14  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 564  bytes 46035 (44.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 348  bytes 28476 (27.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8  bytes 656 (656.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8  bytes 656 (656.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0`
```

接続できないマシン２

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::7a1f:ee33:b18d:644f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:37:f8:46  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1099  bytes 135780 (132.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 907  bytes 153118 (149.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.33.11  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.33.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fef9:94b5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:f9:94:b5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 65  bytes 4638 (4.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 93  bytes 11125 (10.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 76  bytes 6552 (6.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 76  bytes 6552 (6.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:50:73:70  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

ホストマシン　ipconfigの結果
（出して大丈夫かわからなかったのでWireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 2:の結果だけ削除しました）

```
Windows IP 構成


イーサネット アダプター イーサネット:

   メディアの状態. . . . . . . . . . . .: メディアは接続されていません
   接続固有の DNS サフィックス . . . . .:

イーサネット アダプター VirtualBox Host-Only Network #5:

   接続固有の DNS サフィックス . . . . .:
   リンクローカル IPv6 アドレス. . . . .: fe80::7c07:8697:baa:c3eb%15
   IPv4 アドレス . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.56.1
   サブネット マスク . . . . . . . . . .: 255.255.255.0
   デフォルト ゲートウェイ . . . . . . .:

イーサネット アダプター VirtualBox Host-Only Network #6:

   接続固有の DNS サフィックス . . . . .:
   リンクローカル IPv6 アドレス. . . . .: fe80::686c:7b75:6415:4898%13
   IPv4 アドレス . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.33.1
   サブネット マスク . . . . . . . . . .: 255.255.255.0
   デフォルト ゲートウェイ . . . . . . .:

Wireless LAN adapter ローカル エリア接続* 1:

   メディアの状態. . . . . . . . . . . .: メディアは接続されていません
   接続固有の DNS サフィックス . . . . .:

Wireless LAN adapter ローカル エリア接続* 2:

   メディアの状態. . . . . . . . . . . .: メディアは接続されていません
   接続固有の DNS サフィックス . . . . .:
```

nmcli deviceの情報も重要だったと思うので一応載せておきます。
接続できないマシン１

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
enp0s3  ethernet  connected  enp0s3
enp0s8  ethernet  connected  System enp0s8
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

接続できないマシン２

```
DEVICE      TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
enp0s3      ethernet  connected  enp0s3
enp0s8      ethernet  connected  System enp0s8
virbr0      bridge    connected  virbr0
lo          loopback  unmanaged  --
virbr0-nic  tun       unmanaged  --
```

Comment: 接続できるマシンのVagrantfileも記載して頂けますか？

Comment: 念のためホストマシンや接続を試みているマシンに関するネットワークの情報もあると解決へのヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: Picosushi様 cubick様　コメントありがとうございます。
  接続できるvagrant fileは以下です。
   `config.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.3"
   config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 2800, host: 2800
   config.vm.network "public_network", ip: '192.168.1.100'` 
  
  ネットワークの情報はifconfigでよいでしょうか？

Comment: 質問欄にifconfigの結果を張ります。

Answer (score 0):

ブリッジによるネットワークは、ホストマシンが属するネットワークにゲストマシンを登録する？ということだったので、IPの第３オクテットをホストマシンのIPと同じ1にしたらできました！