# Vagrant ブリッジ　ローカル内の別機から仮想マシンに接続したい

Tags: ssh, vagrant

vagrantfileの以下を有効化しました。ホスト部は他とかぶってません。

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.33.100"
```

ゲストマシンに接続して `ifconfig` の結果です。

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ifconfig
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::907d:2b24:c79d:29a9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:37:f8:46  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 958  bytes 117229 (114.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 690  bytes 128780 (125.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.33.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.33.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe82:b4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:82:00:b4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 27  bytes 4020 (3.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17  bytes 1354 (1.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 84  bytes 7232 (7.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 84  bytes 7232 (7.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

以上を確認して別機から `ssh vagrant@192.168.33.100` しましたが、タイムアウトしてしまいます。原因は何でしょうか？

Comment: 別機のifconfigの結果も教えて下さい。またsshではなくpingは通りますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しましたので回答に載せます。

Answer (score 0):

[Vagrantの仮想環境にホストマシン以外からアクセスすると Connetion timed out してしまう](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/55309/vagrant%e3%81%ae%e4%bb%ae%e6%83%b3%e7%92%b0%e5%a2%83%e3%81%ab%e3%83%9b%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%83%9e%e3%82%b7%e3%83%b3%e4%bb%a5%e5%a4%96%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%82%a2%e3%82%af%e3%82%bb%e3%82%b9%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%a8-connetion-timed-out-%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%86)
自分で投稿してすっかり忘れていましたが、ブリッジするときはホストのIPアドレスの第三オクテットとvagrantfileに書く固定ipの第三オクテットを合わせないとだめでした。
なので、ホストのIPの第三オクテットが1でしたので、vagrantfileを以下に書き換えてreloadして解決しました。

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.100"
```